# HTML, JS, Canvas - My JS Scripts with pictures aren't showing up

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, visual-studio-code

I am trying to make 3 " boats " move with JS in a Canvas box.
The problem I am having with my project is as followed: 
I am using an:  statement at the start, but when I wanna use the startGame Function it doesen't show the pictures that I have chosen. It ONLY works so far with the Pic/boat.jpg that i use as background for some unkown reason. Neither my Teacher nor my Classmates knows what the problem is. We have tryed a variety of different things but none seemed to work for me :/ I hope someone can help me out with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="MainC/C.css" />
    <!-- 
    <script src="main.js"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        header {
            background-color: rgb(28, 72, 88);
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 100px;
            opacity: 0.7;
            position: fixed;
            background-image: url(pic/VORIcon.png);
        }

        body,
        html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        canvas {
            border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body background="Pic/boat.jpg" onload="startGame()">
    <header>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#News">News</a>
                <a href="#OCRLive">Live Race</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>




    <script>
        /* When the user clicks on the button, 
        toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
        function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
        }

        // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
        window.onclick = function (event) {
            if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

                var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script>

        var myGamePiece1;
        var myGamePiece2;
        var myGamePiece3;
        var myGamePiece4;

        function startGame() {
            myGameArea.start();
            myGamePiece1 = new component(30, 30, "Pic/Boat.jpg", 10, 30, "image");
            myGamePiece2 = new component(30, 30, "Pic/Boat.jpg", 10, 110, "image");
            myGamePiece3 = new component(30, 30, "Pic/Boat.jpg", 10, 190, "image");
        }

        var myGameArea = {
            canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
            start: function () {
                this.canvas.width = 480;
                this.canvas.height = 270;
                this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
                document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            }
        }

        function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
            this.type = type;
            if (type == "image") {
                this.image = new Image();
                this.image.src = color;
            }
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.update = function () {
                ctx = myGameArea.context;
                if (type == "image") {
                    ctx.drawImage(this.image,
                        this.x,
                        this.y,
                        this.width, this.height);
                } else {
                    ctx.fillStyle = color;
                    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
                }
            }

        }
        function updateGameArea() {
            myGamePiece1.update();
            myGamePiece2.update();
            myGamePiece3.update();
        }

    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

If I need to say anything else or clarify myself some more please tell me so :) I appriciate any help!

Ps: Any Picture besides the background wont work for me.

CSS:

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    min-width: 160px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}
```

Comment: Can you attach a link of jsfiddle or codepen ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/49y1xsfu/ I hope this is fine :) First time I use it.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to add pictures.

Comment: Have a look at this is this what you was trying to do ? https://jsfiddle.net/VIvekJain202/fkc9d7ng/

Comment: @CodeManiac Kind of. But I need it to be something else than the Background picture in those 3 other squares. For me it only works when I use the Background that I use for the body.

Comment: Try adding different image links i used the same link for all the images i think that will work.

Comment: @CodeManiac OMG! It works ! :D Finally. Thanks alot ! But I see you moved around alot of the code. Was it displaced that much ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Actually add the canvas to your html instead of creating it with JS. Remove the inline script and script tags, uncomment the script source tag in your header and move it to the line just below your canvas.

```
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

If that works its just the order in which the script runs and the canvas gets created. It may not be created in time for your script to find the element if that makes sense.

Comment: I am trying, but I gotta be honest. I know very little of using Canvas :)